# ReactJS - Render top level component on load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm toying around with ReactJS, and I'm using Gulp to concatenate my files. Because I can't easily determine the order of my files, and to not populate the global namespace I decided to namespace my application... e.g.

```
App = App || {};

App.Dashboard = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <p>My Dashboard</p>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    <App.Dashboard />,
    document.body
);
```

This seems work fine, however the issue is that `React.render()` has to be after all of the files have loaded. To get around this, I did the following:

File One:

```
App = App || {
    ready: function() {
        React.render(
            <App.Dashboard />,
            document.body
        );
    }
};

$(function() {
    App.ready();
});
```

Other File:

```
App.Dashboard = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <p>My Dashboard</p>
        );
    }
});
```

This works... but it just doesn't feel correct. Is there  better way to go about this?

Comment: If you don't control the order of concatentation of files, you should switch to a build system that will sequence them properly, based on `require` usage. Something like http://browserify.org/ for example. Or http://webpack.github.io/. Using either should mean you can code your `render` function more naturally.

Comment: gulp doesn't do that?  I'd be surprised if that's the case I just recently dabbled with it, but nothing in depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just keep your assets as-is and have a short  section at the end that will run when the body is available for writing.

There's actually a lot of reasons why you don't want to render to document.body though, so I recommend you put a  in your html and use that to render your application. That way, when you have a bootstrap `<script>` section under the `<div>`, that container should be done rendering by the time you want to render to it:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script>
App.ready(); // calls the function which then does   
             // React.render(Component, document.getElementById('app'))
</script>
```

Dan Abramov wrote a bit about this: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375#486f

My own experience fumbling with doc.body: https://twitter.com/jusrin00/status/578331514397679617

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. I'll stick with this approach for now!